# d3 text cut off / goes beyond chart area

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js

Text is going beyond the chart. The idea is if **i** is greater than 1500 and **title length** is greater than 5 characters long then text is shifted to the left by 100px.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ekilja01/pen/WmyPGm)

Here is my approach:

```
let rect = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(combined)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .on('mouseover', function () {

      d3.select(this)
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'text')
        .attr('x', function (d) {
          return xScale(d.revenue);
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
          return yScale.bandwidth() + 175;
        })
        .style('font-size', 10)
        .attr('dy', -20)
        .attr('dx', function (d, i) {
          if (d.title.length > 5 && i > 1500) {
            return -100;
          } else {
            return 10;
          }
        })
        .text(d => d.title)
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
      d3.select('.text')
        .remove();

    });
```

Comment: it's your i > 1500 - that never happens...

Comment: If you want to prevent cutting off the text, you should have a condition like: if (d3.select(this).attr("x") > 400) or better to set the text-anchor based on the position to achieve this

Comment: thanks this works, if you post an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i` refers to the index of the selection elements, since you have just one, `i` never exceeds 0.

If you want to prevent cutting off the text, you should have a condition like:

```
if (d3.select(this).attr("x") > 400)
...
```

or better you set the text-anchor based on the position to achieve this.